# Calling function and running it

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am quite new to objects and OOP. I really don't know how to explain it well but I'll try.

So I am trying to read though JSON with JS, the JSON is passed from PHP. This would be easy if all of the information was on the same html page, but I' am trying something that I am new too.

So let me show my code...

First is the JS which is in app.js

```
   var Donors = function(){
    var api = this.list;

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON(api, function(data){
        var donorObj = data.payload;
        $.each(donorObj, function(i, donor){
          //console.log(donor.ign);
        });
      });
    });

   }
```

What I *want* this part to do is read from the JSON I'm giving it and console.log each name (or donor.ign) when the document is ready.

On the html page, or header.php

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var list = <?php cbProxy(); ?>;
    var Dons = new Donors();
    Dons.list = list;
    });
</script>
```

the data that's in list is the below JSON. You already know what the rest does, it just passes the JSON to the `Donors()` function.

JSON example:

```
{
"code": 0,
"payload": [
{
"time": 1349661897,
"packages": [
"49381"
],
"ign": "Notch",
"price": "15.99",
"currency": "USD"
}
```

I'm use to just making functions and calling it on the same page or file and this is my first doing this kind of function. How can I get the function to run with the data I sent it so it `console.log()` each name?

I did try

```
console.log(Donors());
```

Which only logged `undefined`.

New code:

app.js

```
   var Donors = function(api){

    this.list = api;

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON(this.list, function(data){
        var donorObj = data.payload;
        $.each(donorObj, function(i, donor){
          console.log(donor.ign);
        });
      });
    });

   }
```

index.php/inline script

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var list = <?php cbProxy(); ?>;
    var dons = new Donors(list);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check your error console. For the beginner: Try solving async stuff without OOP at first.

Comment: Doesn't show any error if you mean't console.log... I just don't know how to actually run this..... I'm not new to ajax as I done it many times.

Comment: do you find your doc ready loaded?

Comment: @devs: Ah, you fixed your ajax code now. Actually, I had `$.ajax` expected to throw an error without an URL, but it does just load the current url. If you had used an error handler, you would have seen the exception from the attempt to parse the returned HTML as JSON

Answer (score 1):

If you execute

```
var Dons = new Donors();
Dons.list = list;
```

then you do invoke the constructor function *before* assigning something to the `list` property. That means your `api` variable will be `undefined`, as long as you haven't defined one on the prototype object from which your `Donors` inherit. Instead, pass the list as a parameter to the constructor:

```
function Donors(api) {
    this.list = api;
    // do something
}
var dons = new Donors(list);
```

Comment: 'var dons = new Donors(list);' in '<script>' correct? Console returns Just the object in Dons and 'GET http://localhost/mypage/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: Seems like `list` is not the [expected URL string](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), but some object.

Comment: Does var dons = new Donors(list); execute the function? (Like get the JSON, console.log it)

Comment: Yes. Check out [what the `new` operator does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Comment: Okay take a look at the edit and tell me if it's correct - Now I'm not getting anything in console. No errors, or anything. As I read, it is executing, but I'm not sure why it's not doing anything.

Comment: Should work. Check your network panel for the request. And maybe use `$.ajax({url:this.list, dataType:'json').fail(console.log).done(function(data){…});` instead of `getJSON`, also you could just add a simple log statement in the constructor (outside the ajax)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be this way:

```
$.getJSON(api, function(data){
    $.each(data.payload, function(i, donor){
       console.log(donor.ign);
    });
});
```

try this and see if works.